# comparing two valuestack string values in JSP - struts2

Tags: struts2, ognl

Thanks in advance for your time.

I need to preselect a radio button if it has a saved value. I basically need to compare 2 strings in the valuestack to determine this.

(I can't use `<s:radio` at the moment because of some business rules I need to attach based on other input elements in the form).

I tried to do `<s:set` the value of the saved id inside `s:iterate` like below and then compare them like below but obviously I didnt get it right.

```
<s:set var="savedId" value="%{flag.problemId}"/> 
              <s:iterator value="problemIdList"> 
                    <s:set var="currentId" value='<s:property value="id"/>' />                   
                        <s:if test="%{#currentId.equals(#savedId)}" >
                                <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="problemId" id="problemId" value='<s:property value="id"/>'/> <s:property value="description"/> <br/>
                        </s:if>
                <s:else>
                    <input type="radio" name="problemId" id="problemId" value='<s:property value="id"/>'/> <s:property value="description"/> <br/>
                </s:else>                       
             </s:iterator>
```

Basically I need to compare the two strings, my code is below. I know I can't compare with equals() like I have below - any ideas?

Thanks a bunch!

```
<s:set var="savedId" value="%{flag.problemId}"/>  <s:iterator value="problemIdList">                                 
<s:if test=' <s:property value="id"/>.equals(<s:property value="savedId"/>) '>
    <input checked="checked" type="radio" name="problemId" id="problemId" value='<s:property value="id"/>'/>            <s:property value="description"/> <br/>
</s:if>
<s:else>
    <input type="radio" type="radio" name="problemId" id="problemId" value='<s:property value="id"/>'/>                     <s:property value="description"/> <br/>
</s:else>
```

Regards,
VeeCan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
<s:if test='id.equals(savedId)'>
```

If "id" is a string OGNL will allow you to use methods of String.

Comment: Agreed. This should work for you. The value of the test attribute is evaluated as an OGNL expression.

Comment: Thanks Steven & Quaternion for your input however, id.equals(savedId) does not evaluate to true. During debugging, when I tried id==1 (for one of the records I am testing with), it works. Definitely not hardcoding it, but I don't get it :(

Comment: Ok, I figured it out - `<s:if test="id.equals(flag.problemId)">'` works. @Steven & @Quaternion, Thanks a bunch for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: I needed the # in front of my iterator var to get this to work. Like so:

<s:iterator value="possibleSortKeys" var="possibleKey">
                         <option <s:if test='#possibleKey.equals(sortKey)'>selected="selected"</s:if>

Without the # I would always get NPE from trying to execute .equals

Answer (score 1):

Access value form `<s:iterator>` into `<s:if>` (ognl with `<s:if>` and `<s:iterator>`)

For example: Suppose `loadUserList` is the iterator(containing `UserName` and `Address`) to be iterated in jsp,

```
     UserName:<s:property escape="false" value="userName" />
     Address:<s:property escape="false" value="address" />
     <s:if test='userName.equals("Admin")'>This is admin User</s:if>
     <s:else>This is not an admin user!</s:else>
```

[OGNL with s:if and s:iterator](http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.com/2012/01/ognl-in-struts2-and.html)