# Struts2: comparing 2 variable in If tag not working

Tags: java, struts2

I am retrieving 2 values (user id and profile id) and I've set them in the variable userId and profileId as shown below.

```
<s:set name="userId" value="#session.User.id"/>
<s:set name="profileId" value="%{#parameters['id']}"/>

<s:if test="%{#userId} != %{#profileId}" >

<a href="#" title="Follow" id="follow-btn">
<img src="theme/images/follow.png" alt="like" />
<span>Follow</span>
</a>

</s:if>
```

I have tested by using `<s:property value="%{#userId}" />` and `<s:property value="%{#profileId}" />` and both of them is able to display out the value. However I just can't get it to work in the if tag. Right now, the link button will never display no matter what's the value in those 2 variable.

I'm not sure if the if tag statement is right however I have tried a lot of combination (playing around with the `%{}` and `' '`)

I have a feeling it has something to do with the data type but no matter what I did, the comparison expression just doesn't seem to be working..

Cheers!~

**UPDATE:**
okay I've found out that the problem is in `#profileId`. Probably because the value is from `#parameters['id']` which returns a String value. Is there any way to convert this value to int? I've tried `Integer.parseInt(#profileId)` but that doesn't work.

Comment: try `<s:if test="%{#userId != #profileId}"></s:if>`

Comment: what kind of data type is `User.id`, because if you get a param from http request, it should be `String`, do they have the same type?

Comment: `<s:if test="%{#userId != #profileId}"></s:if>` doesn't work.
User.id is integer data type but as you mentioned, retrieving from http request would convert it to string. So perhaps I should convert the profileId to string first?

Comment: try `<s:set name="userId" value="%{#session.User.id}"/>`

Comment: Still doesn't work. Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996905/comparing-two-valuestack-string-values-in-jsp-struts2 <- in ognl you can call equals method

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<s:if test="#userId != #profileId" >
```